# Problem with all fn Keys for Thinkpad W520

Tags: shortcut-keys

I have a problem with the fn. I used a live version of Ubuntu 11.10 on a USB stick to install Ubuntu on my Thinkpad W520. The fn keys worked perfectly in the live version, but do not work in the installed version. I would like to know what I have messed up. I can't seem to find the fix on google, except for inserting the shortcuts by hand, which seems a little brutal, since I know they can work without prior configuration.

Thanks in Advance.

Edit:

The keys just started working out of the blue. I don't really know what my system did or what maybe I did. However all keys work fine now. Sorry for putting this now useless question here.

Answer (score 1):

This was solved by the OP:

> The keys just started working out of the blue. I don't really know
>   what my system did or what maybe I did. However all keys work fine
>   now.